# Can one detect the date and time format in an ISO8601 string?

Tags: date, datetime, iso8601

It's trivial to find libraries which say they can parse a time or date and time presented in ISO8601. What they all seem to mean is that they can be configured to parse *one format* of ISO8601, for instance by hand-rolling a suitable string format code.

But in fact ISO8601 defines a wide variety of possible formats for representing date and time. For instance, to give a very short list of variations:

- various separators are optional or allowed to be different characters (e.g., you can use a space or "T" between the date and time part, and you can omit hyphens between date components)
- you can represent moments with varying degrees of precision, so that "2018" is a valid ISO8601 string I believe
- you can specify time via day-of-the-month, or day-of-the-year, or week numbers
- you can specify time zone offsets in various ways (e.g,  "+01:00", "+0100", or "+01")
- etc..

You could almost  say, ISO8601 defines an entire DSL for representing dates and times. If you only know a string is an ISO8601-formatted time, you don't know much.

So what I'm wondering is this: Can you read a string, knowing only that it is encoded in *some ISO8601 format*, and reliably infer *which format* it is using? Or are the ISO8601 formats unfortunately defined in such a way that a parser needs to know ahead of time which format is being used?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". Well, I face the actual, practical problem of parsing a string knowing only that it conforms to ISO8601. I think this question is answerable, because it either is or is not possible to auto-detect the format of an ISO8601-formatted string based on the string itself. I just don't know enough about ISO8601 and parsers to tell you. But if the answer is obvious to you, please share!

Comment: You are asking multiple, broad questions where single questions are preferred. You are asking for library recommendations which is not allowed.

Comment: Interesting topic, but not appropriate for Stack Overflow. This site is for narrowly-focused questions with specific programming solutions. Questions leading to ongoing open-ended debates are off-topic here.

Comment: Forget the library recommendation. That’s not the essence of the thing. I’m asking a question about iso8601 formats: “can you detect the one used in a string?”  Just like someone else might ask a question about plaintext encodings like utf-8 vs utf-16: “can you detect the one used in a file?” I have had deal with both questions in real life! This seems pretty narrowly-scoped to me. It’s a yes or no question, and the answer follows directly from the format grammar. I will erase defense to libraries.

Comment: There are many formats for many kinds of date-time values defined by ISO 8601. The standard has specific definitions along with some tolerated variants including the “basic” versions minimizing the use of delimiters. Furthermore some have appeared or disappeared between versions of the standard. The *java.time* classes support most all of the strict formats though I’ve not done an inventory. **If you have a certain format or type of value in mind, ask specifically.** But speculating on ISO 8601 as a DSL, and wondering about “all” formats, are both too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am sorry I confused you. I was trying to explain myself, not to speculate. My question is just: Can you infer the ISO8601 format of a string from the string itself? (Answer: I don't know. That's why I asked.) This is what I need to do to parse text when it is only guaranteed that the text text contains _some_ ISO8601 format. It is exactly like the question, Can you infer the text encoding of a file from the file itself. (Answer: no, which is why you need to track text file encodings out of band.) Please let me know if there is something I could make more clear about this.

Answer (score 3):

It's an interesting question, but the answer is invariably **no**.  To *parse* a string is not only to evaluate its characters, but to evaluate them with specific intent.

In other words, *what would you parse it into*?  If one has a string that might contain a date, and might contain a time, and might contain an offset from UTC, or might contain a week-of-the-year based value, or  might contain a period of elapsed time, and might contain a range of such periods, possibly with a fixed point at one end...   Such a resulting object that could parse *all* of them would not be very useful.  One would have to test a lot of optional properties of that object in order to know how to use it.  Perhaps one might use such an object for validation of the string being in one of a handful of valid formats, but regular expressions are much better suited for that task.

It's worth mentioning that languages that have tried to make one-date-time-type-to-rule-them-all usually have ended up regretting it.  Consider `java.util.Date` which fell into this trap.  Java developers should know by now that they should be using `java.time` or Joda-Time instead.  Also consider schema languages like XSD, which have a wide variety of date and time types defined, many of which are ISO8601 compatible.  If there was only one type, it would devalue the purpose of defining a schema.